# Collections.singletonList works on APIs < 26

Tags: android, collections, target-sdk

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)), `Collections.singletonList` is added on API 26. I have `targetSdkVersion 25` and `minSdkVersion 19` and my app still compiles and runs perfectly on emulators/devices below 26 when I use this method. 
How is this possible ?

Comment: That feels like a documentation bug.

Comment: it is indeed a bug in the documentation